# What is the song that plays in Sirius the Jaeger EP. 4 at 20 minutes 40 seconds?

Tags: music, sirius-the-jaeger

I just finished watching Episode 4 "Beginning of Trickery" of [Sirius the Jaeger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius_the_Jaeger).

**What is the song that plays when  they begin searching the train (starts at 20:40)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Track 6 of the [Original Sound Track](https://sirius-the-jaeger.fandom.com/wiki/Original_Soundtrack): "Theme of Agatha".